# I bought bitcoin years ago and now the website that I bought from is unavailable!

Tags: wallet, private-key, exchanges, public-key, address-generation

I bought bitcoin years ago and now the website that I bought from is unavailable!
I only have a key that I don't even know whether it's a public key or a private key or some useless key generated by the website. Plus I'm not sure that the website bought actual bitcoin or other cryptos for me.
How can I know if I have it on the blockchain?

Comment: Do not post the actual key here! But can you describe what it looks like? Eg how long is it, what characters does it contain, and what character does it start with? That’ll help determine what sort of key it is. If it isn’t a private key, then your bitcoins are likely gone (and perhaps, were never yours in the first place)

Comment: Sure, It has 34 characters and starts with A, it has many different letters (both uppercase and lowercase) and 4 numbers(all lower than 10).

Comment: That doesn't sound to me like a 12 word phrase and so you might be out of luck without having your 12 secret words.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to import the wallet using the key you have (assuming it is a private key) through wallet software such as [bluewallet.io](https://bluewallet.io/), which supports importing of wallets via private keys.

Otherwise, if that key is not your private key, you are a little screwed, sorry.